# Creating a scatter plot with matplotlib with large dataset

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to create a scatter plot from instrument peak area data recorded every tenth of a second or so. For some reason, when I try to plot it with Matplotlib, I get a straight line, which is not at all representative of the data. I feel it may be a syntax error, but I cannot figure it out. I've worked with a few tutorials, and they generally give me the same results, so I am thinking it must be an error in my graphing method.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
  
fig = plt.figure()
  
x = new_df.tIn
y = new_df.In
  
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.yaxis.set_ticks([2000,3000])
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
  
fig.suptitle("What is going on?", fontweight ="bold")  
    
plt.show()
```

And this is the figure I get, which neither reflects my data or the tick marks I was trying to display:
[image: Resulting image]

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Does it have to do with the 'In' having so many decimal places? Thanks in advance!

For reference here is the format of data I am working from:

[image]

Comment: To get a scatter plot you might want to try using `ax.scatter` instead of `ax.plot`.

Comment: Good idea! I tried this and it resulted in the same trend though, with larger marker points.

Comment: Have you tried drawing it with other modules like `seaborn`? Was the result the same? What's that number specified on y-axis?

Comment: @Miss.Alpha I have, I tried it as follows:

```ax = sns.scatterplot(x=df.tIn, y=df.In, data = new_df, color='steelblue')

ax.set(xlabel='Time (s)', ylabel='Peak Intensity (CPS)', title='LCICPMS Results')

plt.show()```
and it resulted the same. The random number on the y axis it generated on it's own based on what I put in for ```ax.yaxis.set_ticks([2000,3000])``` which doesn't match what I put either. I have been successful with a smaller dataset, so it is confusing it is having trouble with 2640 points... compared to other plots I have seen that isn't that much data

Comment: Ok, I got it. It is the datatype, as of now it is an object. a quick ```df[['tIn', 'In']]= df[['tIn', 'In']].astype(str).astype('float')``` Solved the problem.

Comment: That's great that you found a solution to your problem. If you think your answer can help somebody else submit your answer.